# How to inject List<Integer> in spring bean instead List<String>?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

bean definition in application-context.xml

```
<bean id="testMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.List">
            <entry key="test" value="#{'4,6'.split(',')}" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

in java class file

```
@Resource(name = "testMap")
private Map<String, List<Integer>> testMap;
```

when I try to read the value say `testMap.get("test").get(0)*testMap.get("test").get(0)` , I get this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Try `"#{1,2,3,4}"`

Comment: I've hard-coded the string value there but in real I read this value from somewhere else. so I cannot do this.

Comment: Perhaps the stream API helps e.g. `value="#{'4,6'.split(',')}.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())"`.